# Get the full history of the particular page using the mediawiki api

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Hi i have installed media wiki in my domain and i have used the api to get the page details using the following function

```
 $page->getSection('History');
```

But it is only displaying last update of that particular page not full history of that page. Can any one suggest me how can i get the full history of the page using the [Mediawiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what exactly are you doing? Where did you get `$page` from. And it seems you're not actually using [the API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

Comment: i'm using the script from the following url script. Which is the client library of php for mediawiki                                 https://github.com/hamstar/Wikimate/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with client library of your choice, so I'll give you "normal" API url: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New%20York&rvlimit=max&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment ([parameters described here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv)). Note the rvlimit=max parameter. You get 500 revisions instead of 1. See docs to learn how to fetch next 500.

Revisions query normally returns only the most recent revision, so you could try passing "limit", "rvlimit" or whatever to your client library, maybe it supports it. If not, try another one or develop client from scratch.